Show the continuity of solution operator in the nonlinear heat equation
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$. We consider the nonlinear heat equation
\begin{align*}
(P)\left\{\begin{aligned}
u_t-\Delta u&=f(u), &&\Omega\times(0,T),
\\ u&=0, &&\partial\Omega\times(0,T),
\\\ u(\cdot,0)&=g, &&\Omega,
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{align*}
where $g\in L^2(\Omega)$, $f:\ L^2\big((0,T),L^2(\Omega) \big) \longrightarrow L^2\big((0,T),H^{-1}(\Omega) \big)$ be continuous and
\begin{align*}
\exists a>0:\ \big\|f(u)(t)-f(0)(t) \big\|_{H^{-1}}\,\leq\, a\big\|u(t)\big\|_{L^2} \ \text{ a.e on } [0,T],
\end{align*}
for all $ u\in L^2\big((0,T),L^2(\Omega) \big)$.
Define the solution operator
\begin{align*}
S:\ L^2\big((0,T),L^2(\Omega)\big)\cap C\big([0,T],L^2(\Omega)\big)&\longrightarrow L^2\big((0,T),L^2(\Omega)\big)\cap C\big([0,T],L^2(\Omega)\big)
\\ v&\longmapsto Sv
\end{align*}
where $Sv$ is the weak solution of the linear heat equation
\begin{align*}
(P_v)\left\{\begin{aligned}
u_t-\Delta u&=f(v), &&\Omega\times(0,T),
\\ u&=0, &&\partial\Omega\times(0,T),
\\\ u(\cdot,0)&=g, &&\Omega.
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{align*}
In this context, suppose we hold that $S$ is well defined. We establish
\begin{align*}
M\,=\,\Big\{v\in L^2\big((0,T),L^2(\Omega)\big)\cap C\big([0,T],L^2(\Omega)\big) \,\big|\,\|v\|_{C(L^2)}\leq R \Big\},
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\|v\|_{C(L^2)}\,:=\,\sup_{t\in[0,T]}\left(e^{-kt}\|v(t)\|_{L^2} \right)
\end{align*}
and the positive real number $R$ and $k$ is choosen so that $S(M)\subset M$.
I want to show that $S\big|_M:\ M\longrightarrow M$ is continuous.
My attempt

Given $\{v_n\}\subset L^2\big((0,T),L^2(\Omega)\big)\cap C\big([0,T],L^2(\Omega)\big)$ s.t $\big\|v_n-v\big\|_{L^2(L^2)}\to 0$ for some $v\in L^2\big((0,T),L^2(\Omega)\big)$. Consider a subsequence $\{v_{n_k}\}$. Since $Sv_{n_k}$ and $Sv$ are weak solution of the linear heat equation, we have for any $t\in[0,T]$ a.e and $\varphi\in H^1_0(\Omega)$,
\begin{align*}
\int\limits_\Omega (Sv_{n_k}-Sv)_t(t)\varphi +\int\limits_\Omega \nabla(Sv_{n_k}-Sv)(t)\cdot\nabla\varphi=\int\limits_\Omega \big[f(v_{n_k})-f(v)\big](t)\varphi.
\end{align*}
Choose $\varphi=Sv_{n_k}-Sv$, then
\begin{align*}
&\frac{d}{dt}\int\limits_\Omega\big|Sv_{n_k}(t)-Sv(t)\big|^2 +2\int\limits_\Omega \big|\nabla\big(Sv_{n_k}-Sv\big)(t)\big|^2 
\\ =\ &2\int\limits_\Omega\big[f(v_{n_k})-f(v)\big](t)\big(Sv_{n_k}-Sv \big)(t).
\end{align*}
It follows that
\begin{align*}
&\frac{d}{dt} \big\|Sv_{n_k}(t)-Sv(t)\big\|_{L^2}^2+2\big\|Sv_{n_k}(t)-Sv(t)\big\|_{H^1_0}^2
\\ =\ &2\int\limits_\Omega\big[f(v_{n_k})-f(v)\big](t)\big(Sv_{n_k}-Sv \big)(t)
\\ \leq\ &2\big\|f(v_{n_k})(t)-f(v)(t)\big\|_{H^{-1} }\big\|Sv_{n_k}(t)-Sv(t)\big\|_{H^1_0 }
\\ \leq\ &\big\|f(v_{n_k})(t)-f(v)(t)\big\|_{H^{-1}}^2+\big\|Sv_{n_k}(t)-Sv(t)\big\|_{H^1_0 }^2&&\text{(Cauchy inequality)}.
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} \big\|Sv_{n_k}(t)-Sv(t)\big\|_{L^2}^2&\leq\big\|f(v_{n_k})(t)-f(v)(t)\big\|_{H^{-1}}^2-\big\|Sv_{n_k}(t)-Sv(t)\big\|_{H^1_0 }^2
\\ &\leq\big\|f(v_{n_k})(t)-f(v)(t)\big\|_{H^{-1}}^2.
\end{align*}
Integrating both side, we have
\begin{align*}
\big\|Sv_{n_k}(t)-Sv(t)\big\|_{L^2}^2&\leq\int\limits_0^t\big\|f(v_{n_k})(s)-f(v)(s)\big\|_{H^{-1}}^2ds.
\end{align*}
Since $f$ is continuous, we deduce that $\big\|f(v_{n_k})-f(v)\big\|_{L^2(H^{-1})}\to0$, which implies $\big\|f(v_{n_k})(t)-f(v)(t)\big\|_{H^{-1}}\to0$. Therefore, $\big\|Sv_{n_k}(t)-Sv(t)\big\|_{L^2}\to0$, leads to $\big\|Sv_{n_k}-Sv\big\|_{L^2(L^2)}\to0.$

I have doubts that my proof is not really valid, in the final part of showing the convergence of $Sv_{n_k}$. I also haven't seen anywhere to utilize the boundedness in $C\big([0,T],L^2(\Omega)\big)$ of $v_{n_k}$ and $Sv_{n_k}$. Is there any well-known result that can help with this ? Could anyone give me some hints or guidance here ? Thanks.

Given the form of $|\cdot|_{C(L^2)}$, I think the Gronwall inequality has to be used.

@ShuhaoCao  I wonder if we can show that $f$ is bounded with respect to the norm $|\cdot|{L^2(H^{-1})} $. Suppose that holds, then we can show that $\big|Sv{n_k}\big|{L^2(H^1_0)}$ and $\big|\big(Sv{n_k}\big)t\big|{L^2(H^{-1})}$ be bounded, and we can apply the Aubin-Lions lemma then.
